# Install simple-navigation gem, not listed in gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, installation

I install the [simple-navigation gem](https://github.com/codeplant/simple-navigation/wiki) using

> $ gem install simple-navigation

in the dir where gem is stored.I get no errors. Then cd to working dir and type

> $ bundle install

After that, I  cannot see the gem in the installed list when I type

> $ bundle show

As a result, I cannot generate a new navigation menu , using the command

> rails generate navigation_config

I'm new to RoR, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what says `bundle show simple-navigation`? and why don't you wish to add it to Gemfile?

Comment: it says Could not find gem 'simple-navigation'.It's been added when I use 'gem install', isn't it?

Comment: after the `bundle install` it hides gems which are not in Gemfile. so why do you try avoiding the gemfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the file labeled `Gemfile` in the root of your RoR project.
2. Add the following line to the Gemfile: `gem "simple-navigation"`
3. Open a terminal and run `bundle install`

The installation instructions can also be found on the github repo you linked: https://github.com/codeplant/simple-navigation/wiki/Installation